# Redis Caching Does Not Work With Hibernate PersistentBag<Enum>

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, enums, deserialization, spring-data-redis

I have implemented spring data redis caching for my spring boot project. All my caches work except when I try to cache an item which contains a field of List<Enum> type (not the raw Enum class but any enum class I have created in my project eg. List<MyEnum>).

Caches work without a problem if there is an Enum field or a List field, but when there is a list of enums, upon requesting a cached response the json I receive abruptly ends at the enum list field.

I've even implemented a custom json converter for List<Enum> to List<String> conversion but it did not solve my problem.

### Redis Config

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }

}
```

### Expected JSON Response

```json
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "list1": [
    "element1",
    "element2"
  ],
  "enum1": "enumValue1",
  "enumList": [
    "enumValue2",
    "enumValue3",
    "enumValue4"
  ]
}
```

### Received JSON Response

```json
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "list1": [
    "element1",
    "element2"
  ],
  "enum1": "enumValue1",
  "enumList"
}
```

### EDIT

Turns out that my List<Enum> fields are using PersistentBag from Hibernate instead of ArrayList. Right now using `ArrayList<>(enumList)` when assigning a response field seems to solve the problem. Are there any better solutions to this?

Comment: What's the error? What's your code? You've configured JSON serialization somewhere?

Comment: I don't receive any errors, but the cached json response that I get from redis is incomplete and unparsable. I've tried different objects and the json response always breaks at the enum list fields. If I add @JsonIgnore annotations to enum list fields, redis works properly. I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: How are you seeing the JSON response? Calling it via Spring Data should be de-serialising it for you. What's actually stored in Redis?

Comment: Yes, I am receiving the JSON response through calling the @Cacheable method. I can view what's actually stored in redis with MONITOR command but it's very long and I cant understrand anything from it.

Comment: I think the problem is because of the list implementation I use. The project uses hibernate so my lists are not ArrayList but PersistentBag, when I change the list type to ArrayList everything works fine.

Comment: that's exactly the sort of thing you should have mentioned as part of your MCVE

Comment: You are right, I've just discovered that this was the case.